# Distinct Count across Bigquery arrays

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I want to concatenate arrays across rows and then do a distinct count. Ideally, this would work:

```
WITH test AS
(
  SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-01') as date,
  2 as value,
  [1,2,3] as key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-02') as date,
  3 as value,
  [1,4,5] as key
)
SELECT
  SUM(value) as total_value,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(DISTINCT key)) as unique_key_count
FROM test
```

Unfortunately, the `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG` function doesn't support the `DISTINCT` operator. I can unnest the array but then I get a fanout and the sum of the value column is wrong:

```
WITH test AS
(
  SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-01') as date,
  2 as value,
  [1,2,3] as key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-02') as date,
  3 as value,
  [1,4,5] as key
)

SELECT
  SUM(value) as total_value,
  COUNT(DISTINCT k) as unique_key_count

FROM test
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(key) k
```

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing that would allow me to avoid joining in the unnested array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DistinctCount(arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT x) FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
);

WITH test AS
(
  SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-01') as date,
  2 as value,
  [1,2,3] as key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-02') as date,
  3 as value,
  [1,4,5] as key
)

SELECT
  SUM(value) as total_value,
  DistinctCount(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(key)) as unique_key_count
FROM test
```

This avoids having a subquery or needing to join the array with the table (causing duplicate values in the sum).

Comment: This is great, thanks. I want to use this in a query generation tool (Looker), so the subquery approach doesn't actually work for the use case. Interestingly, when I try it with a bunch of data, it's a lot slower. Didn't realise UDFs slow things down so much. The HLL++ approach below is much faster so that may be the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH test AS
(
  SELECT DATE('2018-01-01') AS DATE, 2 AS value, [1,2,3] AS key UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2018-01-02') AS DATE, 3 AS value, [1,4,5] AS key
)
SELECT 
  total_value,
  COUNT(DISTINCT key) unique_key_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(value) AS total_value,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(key) AS all_keys
  FROM test
), UNNEST(all_keys) key
GROUP BY total_value
```

result :

```
Row total_value unique_key_count     
1   5           5
```

In case you you have quite a number of rows in your table - you can easily get to memory/resources issue - in this case you can try using [HyperLogLog++ Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions) for approximate aggregation - see example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH test AS
(
  SELECT DATE('2018-01-01') AS DATE, 2 AS value, [1,2,3] AS key UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE('2018-01-02') AS DATE, 3 AS value, [1,4,5] AS key
)
SELECT
  SUM(value) total_value,
  HLL_COUNT.MERGE((SELECT HLL_COUNT.INIT(key) FROM UNNEST(key) key)) AS unique_key_count
FROM test
```

with result

```
Row total_value unique_key_count     
1   5           5
```

Note: this is approximate aggregations  - so pay attention to `precision` parameter in `HLL_COUNT.INIT(input [, precision])` function

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't played around with the HLL++ functions before

Comment: That was the main purpose of the answer - to introduce those functions. They are usually overlooked :o)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example of the usage of HLL++ functions!! I find the official documentation greatly lacking with clear examples (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions)

Comment: @RogierWerschkull - Take a look at this [Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/counting-uniques-faster-in-bigquery-with-hyperloglog) by one of my most favorite Googlers :o)

Comment: While the HLL approach works, my client wants exact distinct counting. For that, the non-HLL version works of course but is not something that can be generated dynamically with Looker, the BI tool we are using.
Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: @RogierWerschkull - please see first option in my answer - it provides exact distinct counting. if this is still not what you need  - please post your question with all details so we will be able to help :o)

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, I need a solution without the subquery level / where the total value is calculated first. so NOT this structure:
SELECT 
  total_value,
  COUNT(DISTINCT key) unique_key_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(value) AS total_value,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(key) AS all_keys
  FROM test
), UNNEST(all_keys) key
GROUP BY total_value

What I want is just a simple SELECT columns, aggregate function, GROUP BY. The query structure of the original post from alan.

Also, I dont want the slow UDF approach.

Comment: @RogierWerschkull - sounds as reasonable expectations. We will be happy to help if you can post a new question with specific details of your case.

Comment: @RogierWerschkull - got version reflecting your expectations/needs - just post your question and I will post the answer and who knows maybe someone else will come with even better one :o)

Comment: done @MikhailBerlyant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653484/simple-distinct-count-across-bigquery-arrays-without-using-hll-or-udfs