# Simple Distinct Count across Bigquery arrays without using HLL or UDFs

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, distinct-values

Like in the example here, I want to distinct count across BigQuery arrays: [Distinct Count across Bigquery arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485871/distinct-count-across-bigquery-arrays)

However, I have a few extra requirements that make the solution provided in that post feasable for me:

- The solution must **not** use UDFs (*too slow*)
- The solution must **not** use the HLL function (*must be exact)*
- The solution must **not** use the SELECT from SELECT pattern displayed on the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485871/distinct-count-across-bigquery-arrays) solution, *as it needs to aggregate on a flexible group of dimensions that is selected by an end user using a BI tool*

So, while this *extended example* (containing user as a grouping dimension) works using HLL:

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  test AS (
  SELECT
    'A' AS User, DATE('2018-01-01') AS ReportDate, 2 AS value, [1,2,3] AS key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'A' AS User, DATE('2018-01-02') AS ReportDate, 3 AS value, [1,4,5] AS key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' AS User, DATE('2018-01-02') AS ReportDate, 4 AS value, [4,5,6,7,8] AS key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'B' AS User, DATE('2018-01-02') AS ReportDate, 5 AS value, [3,4,5,6,7] AS key )
SELECT
  User,
  SUM(value) total_value,
  HLL_COUNT.MERGE((
    SELECT
      HLL_COUNT.INIT(key)
    FROM
      UNNEST(key) key)) AS unique_key_count
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  user
```

I need a version that accomplishes this *distinct aggregated array counting* with the requirements mentioned above.

Again, this means it also should work properly if I group only on **ReportDate**, an combination of **User / ReportDate** or a scenario where this example is extended with additional dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH test AS
(
  SELECT 'A' AS User, DATE('2018-01-01') AS ReportDate, 2 AS value, [1,2,3] AS key UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS User, DATE('2018-01-02') AS ReportDate, 3 AS value, [1,4,5] AS key UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS User, DATE('2018-01-02') AS ReportDate, 4 AS value, [4,5,6,7,8] AS key UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' AS User, DATE('2018-01-02') AS ReportDate, 5 AS value, [3,4,5,6,7] AS key  
)
SELECT 
  User,
  SUM(IF(flag=0, value, 0)) total_value,
  COUNT(DISTINCT key) unique_key_count
FROM test, UNNEST(key) key WITH OFFSET flag
GROUP BY User
```

with result

```
Row User    total_value unique_key_count     
1   A       5           5    
2   B       9           6
```

Comment: Wow, that looks like an ingenious solution, I am going to try that out in Looker (the BI tool) next week...

Comment: But: is there also a version without unnesting the array?

Comment: having the trend  - I afraid your next question will be 'can we do this without the SELECT?` and I would have to say `Never say Never` . Ok - on a serious note: i don't think in your case you can avoid using unnesting - because of distinct count. if you would just count total entries  - you would be able just use array length, but not when you are looking for distinct. But .. as I mentioned  - never say never - it is possible someone will come with another ingenious solution :o). Meantime consider voting if not yet and let us know result after you will try it

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I would say that if Google actually adds the DISTINCT option to ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG, this should be possible in a real simple way. Created new feature request for that:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759351